# jQuery Ajax - return value to specific DIV

Tags: jquery, ajax

Can one of you jQuery kings please tell me why my script.asp will not load for each separate button? I modified the code form http://www.sitepoint.com/ajax-jquery/.
Thanks

```
<html>  
<head>  
<title>AJAX with jQuery Example</title>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>  
</head>  
<body>  
<div id="wrapper">  

  <script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function(){  
      $(".generate").click(function(){  
        $(this).find('div.quote').load("script.asp");  
      });  
    });  
  </script>

<input type="submit" id="generate1" class="generate" value="Generate!"><br />  
<div class="quote"></div><br><br>  

<input type="submit" id="generate2" class="generate" value="Generate!"><br />  
<div class="quote"></div><br><br>  

<input type="submit" id="generate3" class="generate" value="Generate!"><br />  
<div class="quote"></div>  

</div>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: You should stay consistent with your quotes as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `.find(` finds WITHIN the .generate class (enclosed in)
`.nextAll(` finds all SIBLINGS with the selector applied :first being of course the first one of those selected siblings

```
$(".generate").click(function(){
   $(this).nextAll('div.quote:first').load("script.asp");
});
```

an alterative would be to wrap the input and the quote div in another div and then do:

```
<div class='quoteHolder'>
    <input type="button" id="generate1" class="generate" value="Generate!"><br /> 
    <div class="quote"></div>
</div>

$(".generate").click(function(){
       $(this).parent().find('div.quote').load("script.asp");   
});
```

NOTE: in my example, I changed the input type to 'button' because, it is not really a submit now is it, an that will cause other interesting challenges.

Comment: The King has spoken! Thank you all with a special thanks to King Mark. The first example you gave did not work but the second on did by wrapping the elements in a new DIV. Thanks so very much!

Comment: I wondered about your markup just a bit...the real one probably varied some - I did check it here: http://jsbin.com/awuguf/3/edit#javascript,html,live prior to submission however.  Since you are new to StackOverflow, on an answer you LIKE/Accept click the check to the left to show acceptance. (do not do that super quick to get more/better options) unless you really like one.

Answer (score 3):

`.find()` assumes there are elements nested inside of the element you're querying. Your element, however, is next to the element you're working with.

Try this:

```
$(this).next('.quote').load('script.asp');
```

Comment: Valiant effort gentlemen but neither worked. However, thanks for the direction. I will research the next/nextAll methods.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`nextAll`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) and `first` to select the closest `div.quote` sibling:

```
$(".generate").click(function(){  
    $(this).nextAll('div.quote').first().load("script.asp");  
});
```

[`.find`](http://api.jquery.com/find) finds all descendants of the selector matching the given selector, not siblings like you want.